# How to specify my local .bat file (to run on Gitlab server) in gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've a .bat file which is saved on my desktop. I wanted to run this .bat file in Gitlab runner. I committed and pushed the files to Gitlab. when I created the gitlab-ci.yml file, I entered it like the following:

```
auto:
    script:        

    - cd Users/viakv1/Desktop/Postman-SampleAPI
```

But it's not running on Gitlab server. I'm getting an error like the following:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.7.2 (b5e03c94)
  on nc2dldock02 5b596a8b
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Pulling docker image docker:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:2232c0bbbb8cc9238eefc10721db5662156a2624bc7405dc1cade624dde9aaec for docker:latest ...
Running on runner-5b596a8b-project-226-concurrent-0 via ea7f2931acac...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at a017b30 Update .gitlab-ci.yml
From http://nc2dlutil01/viakv1/Postman
   a017b30..d7fa9e9  master     -> origin/master
Checking out d7fa9e96 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ cd Users/viakv1/Desktop/Postman-SampleAPI
/bin/sh: cd: line 50: can't cd to Users/viakv1/Desktop/Postman-SampleAPI
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 2
```

Can anyone please help me to understand how do I provide the command so that Gitlab will understand that the .bat file is in my local (which has to run on Gitlab server)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when calling a bat script, don't forget to prefix that with '`call`', as illustrated in [issue 1051](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1051).

Second, the path to that script should be one within the repo you have pushed said script to, not an absolute path which is only valid on your machine.